# SIGABRT error in my code in c++

Tags: c++, sigabrt

I am getting SIGABRT error in my code. Can anyone tell me from where it might be coming?

Here's my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        int d=stoi(s,nullptr,2);
        int f=__builtin_popcount(d);
        cout<<f*(f-1)/2+f<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your debugger can definitely tell you that, yes.

Comment: OT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   long long  int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
       long long int n;
        cin>>n;
        string s;
        cin>>s;
       long long int d=stoi(s,nullptr,2);
        long long int f=__builtin_popcount(d);
        cout<<f*(f-1)/2+f<<endl;
    }`enter code here`
}
```

Now Try This

Comment: BTW, the `bits/stdc++.h` is a compiler specific header and not recommended for general usage.

Comment: yes, I know but the problem is SIGABRT error, not a header file.